# Подскажите название этого баннера для Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Доброго дня!

Хочется почитать о том, как реализовывается эта вещь, но не могу даже правильно сформулировать запрос, чтобы найти нужную информацию.

Подскажите, как называется стандартный баннер или уведомление, который показывается пользователям в шапке сайта и в зависимости от операционной системы смартфона дает прямую ссылку на скачивание приложения в appstore или play market, имеет стандартный дизайн для своей операционной системы.

На скрине как раз стандартный баннер, который я поймал при заходе на сайт.

Я так понимаю, что иконка, текстовое содержимое и ссылка автоматом подтягиваются из соответствующего магазина приложений.

[image: скриншот из браузера]

Comment: это совершенно не стандартный баннер. Таких стандартных не существует. Это библиотека (модуль для `JQuery`, чтоли), который надо подключить к своему сайту, и настроить. П. С. к `Android` вопрос не имеет отношения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это предложение об установки приложения, вот пример для IOS `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="...">`
Подробнее на [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html). Думаю для android нечто похожее.